# DNS: return address within domain name itself

Tags: domain-name-system

I recall having used a DNS "service", where I would type the address I want to be returned *within the domain name* itself. Example: `192.168.10.9.nit.io` would return `192.168.10.9`. I just can't remember what's the correct domain for this (say, it is not ".nit.io").

It is especially useful when testing a service that will run later under a DNS name but for which I cannot yet create a real DNS record. Using this service, everything runs as if there were a DNS record.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, it is `nip.io`, see https://nip.io/

> nip.io allows you to do that by mapping any IP Address to a hostname
>   using the following formats:
>
> ```
> 10.0.0.1.nip.io maps to 10.0.0.1
> ```

Example:

```
$ dig 192.0.2.42.nip.io +short
192.0.2.42
```